# how to use array_push() in JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I'm new to JavaScript , I have a problem to get new array like

```
one array result
day = ['sday','mday','tday'];
val = [1,2,3]
```

when I use array push

```
var array = [];
    $.each(resp.result, function(index, item) {
    array.push(item.day);
    array.push(item.val );
    });

output :- ['sday',1,'mday',2,'tday',3];
```

but I need

```
output :- ['sday',1],['mday',2],['tday',3]
```

Comment: try `array.push([item.day, item.val]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the answer by D.Seah in comment section, But we need answer in answer field also. use

> array.push([item.day,item.val]);